# Can not run codes in IO Exception when exception was happened

Tags: android, exception, ioexception, bufferedinputstream

I try to `run codes in IO exception` in my codes.

But looks like it not worked, I don't know why.

People who know, please tell me how to run codes in `catch` exception when Exception occurred.

Thanks,

p/s : `Codes` :

```
try {
                        mAlThumbnail.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                                (InputStream) new URL(URL).getContent()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // THIS LINE CAN RUN, I CAN SEE DETAIL EXCEPTION
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        // THESE LINES CAN NOT RUN, I DON'T KNOW WHY, DON'T SEE ANY LOGS
                        // if can not load file because of low connection
                        // should load default image
                        Log.i("", "SET DEFAULT IMAGE");
                        mAlThumbnail.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.iv_loading_file_failed));
                    }
```

`Exception` appeared in `e.printStackTrace()` :

> java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed 01-07 14:23:08.615
>
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.streamClosed(BufferedInputStream.java:118)
>
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(BufferedInputStream.java:112)
>
> libcore.net.http.UnknownLengthHttpInputStream.available(UnknownLengthHttpInputStream.java:53)
>
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(BufferedInputStream.java:114)
>
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method) 01-07
>
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
>
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:696)
>   controller.feature_card.GetPreviewDownloadThumbnailAsync.doInBackground(GetPreviewDownloadThumbnailAsync.java:88)
>
> controller.feature_card.GetPreviewDownloadThumbnailAsync.doInBackground(GetPreviewDownloadThumbnailAsync.java:26)
>
> android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 01-07 14:23:08.620
>
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 01-07
>
> android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 01-07
>
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 01-07 14:23:08.620
>
> BufferedInputStream is closed 01-07 14:23:08.620
>
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.streamClosed(BufferedInputStream.java:118)
>
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(BufferedInputStream.java:112)
>
> libcore.net.http.UnknownLengthHttpInputStream.available(UnknownLengthHttpInputStream.java:53)
>
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(BufferedInputStream.java:114)
>
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method) 01-07
>
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
>
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:696)
>
> controller.feature_card.GetPreviewDownloadThumbnailAsync.doInBackground(GetPreviewDownloadThumbnailAsync.java:88)
>
> controller.feature_card.GetPreviewDownloadThumbnailAsync.doInBackground(GetPreviewDownloadThumbnailAsync.java:26)
>
> android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 01-07 14:23:08.625
>
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 01-07
>
> android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 01-07
>
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Comment: Are you able to see this Log.i("", "SET DEFAULT IMAGE") in your LogCat?

Comment: @Vivek Can not :( I choose all logs, only see exception.

Comment: @Alex.Ok, have you debug the code? OR change the sequence of e.printStackTrace(). put the code above that. Just try this.